# Slice of String vs Slice &String

Tags: rust, slice

I was reading the doc from rust lang website and in chapter 4 they did the following example:

```
let s = String::from("hello world");

let hello = &s[0..5];
let world = &s[6..11];
```

`hello` is of type `&str` that I created from a variable `s` of type `String`.

Some rows below they define the following function:

```
fn first_word(s: &String) -> &str {
    let bytes = s.as_bytes();

    for (i, &item) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        if item == b' ' {
            return &s[0..i];
        }
    }

    &s[..]
}
```

This time `s` is of type `&String` but still `&s[0..i]` gave me a `&str` slice.
How is it possible? I thought that the correct way to achieve this would be something like `&((*str)[0..i])`.

Am I missing something? Maybe during the `[0..i]` operation Rust *auto deference* the variable?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe during the `[0..i]` operation Rust *auto deference* the variable?

This is exactly what happens. When you call methods/index a reference, it automatically dereferences before applying the method. This behavior can also be manually implemented with the `Deref` trait. `String` implements the `Deref` with a target of `str`, which means when you call `str` methods on `String`. Read more about deref coercion [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's important to realize what happens with `&s[1..5]`, and that it's `&(s[1..5])`, namely, `s[1..5]` is first first evaluated, this returns a value of type `str`, and a reference to that value is taken. In fact, there's even more indirection: `x[y]` in rust is actually syntactic sugar for `*std::ops::Index::index(x,y)`. Note the dereference, as this function always returns a reference, which is then dereferenced by the sugar, and then it is referenced again by the `&` in our code — naturally, the compiler will optimize this and ensure we are not pointlessly taking references to only dereference them again.

It so happens that the `String` type does support the `Index<Range<usize>>` trait and it's `Index::output` type is `str`.

It also happens that the `str` type supports the same, and that it's output type is also `str`, *viā* a blanket implementation of `SliceIndex`.

On your question of auto-dereferencing, it is true that Rust has a `Deref` trait defined on `String` as well so that in many contexts, such as this one, `&String` is automatically cast to `&str` — any context that accepts a `&str` also accepts a `&String`, meaning that the implementation on `Index<usize>` on `String` is actually for optimization to avoid this indirection. If it not were there, the code would still work, and perhaps the compiler could even optimize the indirection away.

But that automatic casting is not why it works — it simply works because indexing is defined on many different types.

Finally:

> I thought that the correct way to achieve this would be something like &((*str)[0..i]).

This would not work regardless, a `&str` is not the same as a `&String` and cannot be dereferenced to a `String` like a `&String`. In fact, a `&str` in many ways is closer to a `String` than it is to a `&String`. a `&str` is really just a fat pointer to a sequence of unicode bytes, also containing the length of said sequence in the second word; a `String` is, if one will, an extra-fat pointer that also contains the current capacity of the buffer with it, and owns the buffer it points to, so it can delete and resize it.